# TYPO3: Using IS NULL and COALESCE in OrderBy with TYPO3 Querybuilder

Tags: typo3, query-builder, extbase, doctrine-dbal

I want to using the query

```
SELECT `uid` FROM `machines` ORDER BY NOT ISNULL(`changed`),`changed` DESC
```

in my controller .
For this I use the querybuilder like this:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('forklifts');
$statement = $queryBuilder
    ->select('*')
    ->from('machines');
```

I tryed to add the ORDERBY in this way:

```
$statement->orderBy("NOT ISNULL(`changed`)");
$statement->addOrderBy("changed", "DESC");
```

But this don't work.
Is it possible to do this in TYPO3 Querybuilder or is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QueryBuilder::add()` to bypass this limitation:

```php
$queryBuilder->add(
    'orderBy',
    $queryBuilder->expr()->isNotNull('changed'),
    true
);
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('changed', 'DESC');
```

This is basically what `QueryBuilder::addOrderBy()` does internally but without automatic identifier quoting. Notice that the `ExpressionBuilder` is used here instead of a plain SQL snippet to ensure the `changed` field name is still quoted, even as part of a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mathias for pushing me in the right direction.

In the TYPO3 documentation https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/ExpressionBuilder/Index.html

```
expr()->not()
```

is not listed as a method of TYPO3 querybuilder.

But

```
expr()->isNotNull()
```

is existing.

So this will work:

```
$queryBuilder->add(
    'orderBy',
    $queryBuilder->expr()->isNotNull('changed'),
    true
);
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('changed', 'DESC');
```

Thank you again

Comment: Thanks, I've adjusted my answer, you can remove yours for clarity if you like.